# Weapon jitter when playing FPS animationw

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 3d

I extracted drg’s auto cannon, and the gun and arms are separated models.

When I try to get them into unity, something wrong happened, I tried a lot of methods. Like using script to attach, using Position constrains and rotation constrain, but still can’t fix this issue. I even tried IK, not working.as well.

In my case, I play the running animation in the arm and the gun was not playing animations.

This is the video can show my problem. https://youtu.be/9NA0uNwgCwo?si=WaJjPW4akNNt-mKD

And here is what looks like in Blender https://youtu.be/oA2RqO2fCh8?si=wCbcloWc7GUHT2Qf

And here is how I put models in unity
[Arm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdd06.png)
[Weapon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Argsn.png)

I want to remove the jitter shake issue

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I managed to solve this by myself, in the import setting, the animations are compressed by default for some reasion, I have to disable it to solve this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).